# Timer's function gets called after invalidating

Tags: swift, timer

I am making an application that fetches new data every 10 seconds and inserts it to a tableView.

---

```
    func setupTimer(){
        var timerInterval : TimeInterval = 10.0
        fetchWorldMessagesTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timerInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(fetchNewData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    func invalidateTimer(){
        fetchWorldMessagesTimer?.invalidate()
        fetchWorldMessagesTimer = nil
        fetchWorldMessagesTimer = Timer()
    }
```

It calls `fetchNewData` every 10 seconds.

When a user logs in, I setup the timer.

It works fine.

Now, If the user logs out, it invalidates it, right..
But after logging in again, the previous invalidated timer Fires one more time, and the same time the new timer fires too.. Like:

```
19:00:00 Function called
19:00:10 Function called
Logged out
Logged in
19:00:23 Function called // Problem
19:00:23 Function called
19:00:33 Function called
19:00:43 Function called
```

How could I fix this? It confuses my app and gets it crashed..

---

**Actual code:**

```
// added new values to dataArray
// tableViewInserts = new rows that should be added to the tableView
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: tableViewInserts, with: .fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

**Actual output first time logging in:**

```
Inserting, time: 1526836900.29165
Before inserting into the tableView...
Number of rows in tableView: 0
Number of rows in dataArray: 7
After inserting...
Number of rows in tableView: 7
Number of rows in dataArray: 7

Inserting, time: 1526836910.08356
Before inserting into the tableView...
Number of rows in tableView: 7
Number of rows in dataArray: 7
After inserting...
Number of rows in tableView: 7
Number of rows in dataArray: 7
```

**Actual output after second login:**

```
Inserting, time: 1526836998.48148
Before inserting into the tableView...
Number of rows in tableView: 0
Number of rows in dataArray: 7
After inserting...
Number of rows in tableView: 7
Number of rows in dataArray: 7

Inserting, time: 1526836998.48839
Before inserting into the tableView...
Number of rows in tableView: 0
Number of rows in dataArray: 14

2018-05-20 19:23:18.488901+0200 PipeTest[4249:1705076]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.
The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (14)
must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0),
plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (7 inserted, 0 deleted)
and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Comment: Why do you assign an empty `Timer()` at the end of `invalidateTimer`? How is the "Actual code" section related to the timer? (I don't see `setupTimer()` or `invalidateTimer()` called anywhere.) When do you call `setupTimer`?

Comment: @RobNapier some stackoverflow user said this might help, but it does nothing :/

Comment: Do you know for certain that you call `invalidateTimer` exactly once for every time you call `setupTimer`. You have no logging, so it's not clear that this is true.

Comment: (They were probably just recommending that you assign an empty `Timer` so you didn't need an Optional. That at least would make some sense.)

Comment: Setting the timer up as an optional works fine for me

Answer (score -1):

```
var timer: Timer?

func startTimer() {
    let timerInterval : TimeInterval = 0.5
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timerInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(fetchNewDate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func invalidateTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}

@objc func fetchNewData() {
    print("New Data")
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code with no explanation of any kind. Please include details about what was wrong and how this answer solves the problem.